# What are the custom targets you all run when using ant to build project?

Tags: ant, build-process, cvs, report

I am thinking of running this custom targets to find out more about my project build status
- jalopy
- jdepend
- cvs tagdiff report
- custom task for NoUnit
- generate UML diagram. ESS-Model

What are your views?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's a great idea and use it myself.  That way I'll never forget to run it.

I also keep the reports for a decent amount of time and eventually create a spreadsheet of "progress".

In your main ant task - call another task to do "whatever"

and
JDepend.xml ...

```
<target name="statsAll">
    <!-- master file that describes where everything is -->
    <property file="./ant/ant-global.properties" prefix="ant-global" />
    <tstamp>
          <format property="gen.time" pattern="yyyyMMdd_hh"/>
    </tstamp>
    <echo message="LOG:./ant/logs/jdepend.${version.FILETAG}.${gen.time}.rpt"/>
    <!-- generate stats to see if we're improving -->
    <jdepend 
        outputfile="./ant/logs/jdepend.${version.FILETAG}.${gen.time}.rpt" >
  <exclude name="java.*"/>
  <exclude name="javax.*"/>
    <classespath>
    <pathelement location="./jar" />
      </classespath>
      <classpath location="./jar" />
    </jdepend>
</target>

<target name="doJDepend" depends="getVersion,statsAll">
    <echo message="FTP'ing report"/>
    <ftp verbose="yes" passive="yes" depends="yes"
        remotedir="/videojet/metrics" server="xxxxx"
        userid="xxxx" password="xxxxx"
        binary="no"
        systemTypeKey="UNIX">
        <fileset dir="./ant/logs/" casesensitive="no">
          <include name="**/jdepend.${version.FILETAG}*.rpt"/>
          <exclude name="**/*.txt"/>
        </fileset>
    </ftp>
</target>
```

[Magic build machine](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000149.html)

Answer (score 0):

I second the 'good idea' part, although for a project of reasonable size you might want to make it part of an automated build, like one of the CI Servers (Bamboo, Contiuum).

You might also consider a code coverage tool to see how your test coverage is going.

This will ensure the reports get run on a regular basis, could give you somewhere to publish them and won't slow down the developer's quick turnaround development cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I also think some reports about your project are a good idea. My template-project for an ant-build-script ([Antiplate](http://antiplate.origo.ethz.ch/)) has at the moment the following reports: Junitreport, emma-report, PMD, CPD and Checkstyle. I'm thinking about including a JDepend-report.

At work we use these templates and using Hudson as continuous-integration-system. Hudson creates wonderful graphs for these reports and how the measures changed with the builds.